# What are these entries in my Nginx access.log file and can I exclude them?

Tags: docker, nginx

When I launch a `nginx` webserver via `docker` and check the `access.log` I can see the following entries:

```
...
10.255.0.2 - - [10/Aug/2019:11:53:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "a10hm/1.0"
10.255.0.2 - - [10/Aug/2019:11:53:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2125 "-" "a10hm/1.0"
10.255.0.2 - - [10/Aug/2019:11:53:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2125 "-" "a10hm/1.0"
10.255.0.2 - - [10/Aug/2019:11:53:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "a10hm/1.0"
10.255.0.2 - - [10/Aug/2019:11:53:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2125 "-" "a10hm/1.0"
...
```

They are added almost every second as long as my `docker` swarm is running. I don't understand where they're coming from; are they expected to be there? (Some feature of `docker` perhaps?) and is there a way I can prevent them from appearing and bloating the size of my `access.log` file?

Update:

Even if I simply run `docker run --publish 80:80 nginx` I can still see these messages appearing in the terminal every second.

Comment: Does your Docker Swarm cluster do a health check on the Nginx container by chance?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne I haven't added any settings for health checks. Do you know if this is this default behaviour? I can't see any mention of these entries in people's access.log files anywhere else..

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think restart policies could have a hand on this, but I could be wrong. I haven't personally used Swarm much, I always use third-party cluster managers.

Comment: I'm not sure it is to do with Swarm now. Even if I just run `docker run --publish 80:80 nginx` from the command line I'm still seeing this entries. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CSharp did you end up figuring this out iam having same issue

Comment: @TungamiraiMangombe I never found out what it was but added code in the conf file to  filter it out. Sorry, I haven't got access to that file anymore. I shouldn't affect the functionality of your server, however.